# write the following **sentences** into **quantified statements.**

Tags: predicate-logic

In a domain of natural numbers, use $P(x)$ for $x$ is prime and $Q(x)$ for $x$ is even. Also the symbols $ \ <,>$ for $x$ and  $=$  for $y$  can be used.

Then write the following **sentences** into **quantified statements.**

(i) **Some primes are even**.

(ii) **All even numbers are greater than  $ 1 $ .**

**Answer:**

I tried to write as follows:

(i) 'some primes are even' can be written as $ \exists  <,> (\wedge Q(x)) $

**Am I right ? 
Any help ?**

Comment: The proper way to include text within MathJax is by using \text{}, thus: $$ \begin{align} A & = B + C \\ & = D+E, \text{by Xmith's theorem.} \end{align} $$ But in this case there was no reason for it to be within MathJax, so I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: "Also the symbols  $<,>$ for $x$ and $=$ for $y$ can be used." This sentence seems corrupted.  Could you check your source?

Comment: We can replace $ x \ \ by \ \ the \ symbol \  <,> $  and $ \ y \ by \ the \ symbol \ = $ . That's it.

Comment: Can I write the first sentence as : $ ( \exists x) P(x) \rightarrow Q(x) $

Comment: Yes you can, although,  $~\exists x~(P(x)\to Q(x))$ would be clearer, but also *incorect*.  $~$ What you want to say is: "There exists something which is prime *and* is even."  Try again.

Comment: But it wouldn't be right... (I'm not talking of the style of parenthesization.)

Comment: $ \exists x(P(x) \rightarrow P(x) \wedge Q(x) )$ . Is it ?

Comment: I need the quantified statement only .

Comment: @mabmath.  Universal quantifiers are restricted by implication; Existentials are restricted by conjunction.  Don't missmatch them.

Comment: So how do I write ?

Comment: An English sentence of the form, "Some As are Bs" is first re-written as "There is an $x$ that is both an A and a B."  From there the translation into formula is straightforward.

Comment: can I write the first statement as : $ (\exists x) (\exists y) [P(x) \wedge Q(y)] $.  How can I write for the second sentence ?

Comment: You could, but it would not say what you need to say.  Read it back into English: There's an $x$ that is a prime and there's a $y$ that is even.  Not quite right...

Comment: That is ok, but How can I write the statement " all even numbers are greater than 1 " ?  If I write as  : $ (\forall x)(Q(x) >1) $. Is it partly ok ?

Comment: Partly OK, but $Q(x)$ is either true or false and cannot be compared to an integer.  Instead, you can use $x > 1$ in your sentence.

Comment: But $ Q(x) $ means even numbers .

Comment: You want "for any number, *if* it is even, *then* it is greater than one."

Comment: please help me writing this one . Because I am in confusion .

Comment: There's a lot of detailed advice in the comments by Graham and me.  Try to relax and follow it instead of rushing to the next guess.  Of course, a number of people on this site could just provide you with the solution, but what would you learn?

Comment: "Some primes are even" must be translated as "there are some $x$ that are *prime* and *even*": $\exists x \ (P(x) \land Q/(x))$.

Comment: "All even numbers are greater than 1" must be transalted as: "for every number $x$, if $x$ is even, then $x$ is greater that 1": $\forall x \ (Q(x) \to (x > 1))$.

Comment: The issue is: it seems thta you have **no** symbol for $1$ in your language.

Answer (score 2):

**Existential quantification is restricted by conjunction.**

"Some A-things are B-things," means "There exists something which is an A-thing *and* is a B-thing." $$\exists x~\big(A(x)\wedge B(x)\big)$$

**Universal quantification is restricted by implication** (conditional).

"All A-things are B-things," means "Take anything, *if* it is an A-thing, *then* it is a B-thing." $$\forall x~\big(A(x)\to B(x)\big)$$

Comment: For the next one, I wrote as : $ (\forall x >1 ) (Q(x) >1 )$. is it ok ?

Comment: No.  $(Q(x)>1)$ would be "the truth-value of '$x$ is even' is greater than 1."  You cannot compare a predicate to an integer.

Comment: $ (\forall x) [(x>1) \rightarrow  greater (Q(x), 1)]$. This one is valid or not